# Error while unpacking ArcGIS Desktop Tutorial Data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation

**Hardware**
Hp Compaq dc5700 Microtower
64bit Operating system
Intel pentium dual CPU e2180 @ 2.00 GHz
Memory 4GB

**Software**
Windows 7 home Premuim Service Pack 1
ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1

I have just begun training on the ArcGIS Desktop software. As part of the training material I have managed to download the software with little or no problem. However when ever I try to unpack the training files I get the following error message.

[image]

Error code 2147467259

I have run a scan on the downloaded file using 7zip and it shows 5 errors,please see below;[image]

While looking for similar solutions I came across reports of people looking to install SQL related softare who fixed their issue. The person who had the issue stated

"I reset the .net permission on the 2008 server buy running : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -machine -reset"

I have attempted this step with no success.